# Flutter Firebase notification default iOS sound not working sent from firebase console

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
await firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {


    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage((RemoteMessage message) async{


    });
```

Notification works perfect and on Android has a sound but on iOS no sound how to solve this?